# Objective-C - NSArray to NSString with multiple delimiters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an NSArray of strings that I would like to put into a single `NSString` and separate the elements with multiple delimiters in `objective-c`.

For example the array Looks like this.

["Mike", "Brother", "Sarah", "Sister", "Jane", "Sister"]

And I would like them to look like this in the string.

```
"Mike,Brother; Sarah,Sister; Jane,Sister"
```

i.e the person and the relationship is separated by a comma and the siblings are separated by a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *input = [ @"Mike", @"Brother", @"Sarah", @"Sister", @"Jane", @"Sister" ];
NSMutableArray *nameSiblingPairs = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [input count]; i += 2)
    [nameSiblingPairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", input[i], input[i + 1]]];

NSString *output = [nameSiblingPairs componentsJoinedByString:@"; "];
```

Comment: awesome, thanks @dreamlax. Could you maybe edit your answer and show how to do the exact opposite. i.e from output (NSString) to input (NSArray).

Comment: NSArray *array = [output componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: NSArray *array = [outputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",;"]];    Checkout my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"Mike", @"Brother", @"Sarah", @"Sister", @"Jane", @"Sister"];
NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i<[array count]; i+=2){
  [newArray addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", array[i-1],array[i]]];
}
NSString* s = [newArray componentsJoinedByString:@"; "];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a more **better** and **clean** approach

```
NSArray *input = [ @"Mike", @"Brother", @"Sarah", @"Sister", @"Jane", @"Sister" ];
NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString string];
NSArray *delimiters = [@",", @"; "];

for(int i=0; i < outputString.count; ++ i) {

    [outputString appendString:[input objectAtIndex:i]];

    if (i < input.count - 1) {
        [outputString appendString:i % delimiters.count];
    }
}
```

**To get back the array**

```
NSArray *array = [outputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",; "]];
```

**This is a dynamic code where you can add `n` number of delimiters**

Comment: `indexOfObject:` is an O(n) operation, making your overall algorithm O(n^2), when it really could stay O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop with `appendFormat` will work:

```
BOOL first=YES;
NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0 ; i+1 < array.length ; i+=2) {
    if (!first) {
        [res appendString:@"; "];
    } else {
        first = NO;
    }
    [res appendFormat:@"%@,%@", array[i], array[i+1]];
}
```

The use of `NSMutableString` helps to avoid creating temporary objects.

Of course this is not ideal, because items in the array are related. You would be better off making objects that could store both the name and the relationship, so that you wouldn't have to store them in adjacent elements of a flat array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (NSString *)serialize:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSUInteger count = [array count];
    NSAssert(count % 2 == 0,  @"Array count must be even");
    NSString *result = @"";
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count / 2 + 2 ; i+=2) {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",array[i], array[i+1]];

        result = [result stringByAppendingString:temp];
        if (i < count / 2) {
            result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"; "];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

NSArray+Extension.h

```
@interface NSArray (Extension)
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByStrings:(NSArray *)separatorStrings;
@end
```

NSArray+Extension.m

```
@implementation NSArray (Extension)

- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByStrings:(NSArray *)separatorStrings {
    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self count]; i += 1){
        NSMutableString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self[i], separatorStrings[i% [separatorStrings count]]];
        [newString appendString:tempString];
    }
    return newString
}

@end
```